# How to compare all columns after group by?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a PostgreSQL table with a

```
date      | c1    | c2    | count
----------+-------+-------+------
2015-12-22  A       B       1
2015-12-30  C       D       2
2015-12-31  A       B       3
2015-12-31  A       C       5
2016-01-01  A       B       1
2016-01-01  A       D       7
2016-01-01  B       C       1
2016-01-03  B       D       3
2016-01-03  C       D       1
```

What I want to get is a table with a row for each day, which shows how often two persons interacted with each other at that specific day:

```
date       |AB |AC |AD |BC |BD |CD
-----------+---+---+---+---+---+--
2015-12-22  1   0   0   0   0   0
2015-12-30  0   0   0   0   0   2
2015-12-31  3   5   0   0   0   0
2016-01-01  1   0   7   1   0   0
2016-01-03  0   0   0   0   3   1
```

I have already sorted the persons by their names (`c1 < c2`) but I don't know how to compare all of those possible persons and select them as a new column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation.  Assuming that `c1` < `c2`:

```
select date,
       sum(case when c1 = 'A' and c2 = 'B' then cnt else 0 end) as AB,
       sum(case when c1 = 'A' and c2 = 'C' then cnt else 0 end) as AC,
       sum(case when c1 = 'A' and c2 = 'D' then cnt else 0 end) as AD,
       sum(case when c1 = 'B' and c2 = 'C' then cnt else 0 end) as BC,
       sum(case when c1 = 'B' and c2 = 'D' then cnt else 0 end) as BD,
       sum(case when c1 = 'C' and c2 = 'D' then cnt else 0 end) as CD
from t
group by date
order by date;
```

Comment: would it also be possible to create those from a list/query? I have a lot of persons, that's why I would not like to declaring them all.

Comment: @vtri . . . Then you have a dynamic query problem.  You should ask *another* question, because that is very different from this question.  (If you change this question, you will invalidate this answer, which is likely to draw downvotes).